# java PrinterDialog seemingly fails on Windows while working on Mac

Tags: java, javafx

I am writing a small java app to control the order process for a friend.

I am using the PrinterDialog construct to call the system printers and it seems to work pretty well on my Mac under development. However when I try the same code on a Windows machine the code will not open the system printer dialogue. There is no obvious "code failure", just nothing happens. I have tried copying the Jar file to windows and also re-compiling the project on NetBeans within Windows and neither seems to make any difference. There was a thread similar to this a year or two back but the writer seemed to imply simply re-building the project on a Windows machine had solved the problem when, for me, it seems to make no difference.

Any comments or pointers to get the app to work on Windows would be gratefully received.

The code in question is:-

```
    private void actionPrint(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        Stage printStage = new Stage();
        FXMLLoader ploader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("OrderDocument.fxml"));
        Node orderNode = (Node) ploader.load();
        Group printerNode = new Group();
        printerNode.getChildren().add(orderNode);

        Scene printScene = new Scene(printerNode, 620, 875);
        printStage.setScene(printScene);

        Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
        PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, Printer.MarginType.HARDWARE_MINIMUM);
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
        job.showPrintDialog(printStage);
        if (job != null) {
            boolean success = job.printPage(pageLayout,printerNode);
            if (success) {
                job.endJob();   
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(OrderCreateController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}
```

Comment: OK  think I have "solved" it, though am unclear why the version above worked on Mac when it needed the tweak shown below to work on Windows. So I will leave this open for a few days in case anyone has any thoughts on that conundrum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line calling "showPrintDialog" has as its owner the stage on which I built the order document.

However re-reading the usage of "showPrintDialog" I now think it should refer to my main stage and when I effected this change the code worked on both Windows and Mac.

I am a little puzzled as to why the above code did work on Mac in the first place and this rather blinded me to finding it as a solution on Windows, so if anyone has any thoughts on that I will leave this open for a few days.